# Where are Audacity effects chain files saved to on MacOS?

Tags: effects, audacity, location, files, chain

Trying to import an effects chain file from my Windows 10 system but can't find the effects chain files anywhere in the Audacity Package Contents here on MacOS High Sierra.

Comment: A user-setting would never be inside the App package on Mac, it would most likely be in ~/Library/Application Support/ or possibly ~/Library/Audio/

Comment: tetsujin Yes, it was in ~/Libary/Application Support/Audacity/Chains . Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Let me drop that to an answer for future Googlers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac, user configurations would always be saved to that account's own Library `~/Library`, then in either `/Application Support/`, or sometimes for shared audio plugins etc, in `/Audio/`.

Specifically for Audacity chains, they're in `~/Library/Application Support/Audacity/Chains/`

Comment: NOTE: **Library** is misspelled in the path above. Wouldn't have noticed, but I tried copying and pasting it.